# Why do aggregate functions alter the way my rows are fetched?

Tags: mysql, optimization

Running this query

```
SELECT
    s0.id,
    s0.symbol,
    YEARWEEK(p0.datetime) AS label,
    p0.id AS point_id,
    p0.datetime,
    KG_FIRST(p0.open, p0.datetime) AS open,
    MAX(p0.high) AS high,
    MIN(p0.low) AS low,
    KG_LAST(p0.close, p0.datetime) AS close,
    SUM(p0.volume) AS volume
FROM stock s0
LEFT JOIN point p0 ON s0.id = p0.stock_id
WHERE (s0.symbol = 'AMD') AND (p0.datetime BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(p0.datetime)
ORDER BY p0.datetime ASC;
```

results in the following `EXPLAIN` output:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                             | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s0    | const | PRIMARY,UNIQ_4B365660ECC836F9             | UNIQ_4B365660ECC836F9 | 767     | const |     1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p0    | ref   | idx_stock_id_datetime,IDX_B7A5F324DCD6110 | idx_stock_id_datetime | 4       | const | 75829 | Using where                                  | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Now, let's make the same query but without any aggregate functions

```
SELECT
    YEARWEEK(p0.datetime) AS label,
    s0.id,
    s0.symbol,
    p0.id AS point_id,
    p0.datetime
FROM stock s0
LEFT JOIN point p0 ON s0.id = p0.stock_id
WHERE s0.symbol = 'AMD' AND (p0.datetime BETWEEN '2010-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2012-01-01 00:00:00')
GROUP BY YEARWEEK(p0.datetime)
ORDER BY p0.datetime ASC;
```

This makes the query execute considerabely faster (about 20x). One would think it's because the aggregate functions caused the slowdown. Obviously, but `EXPLAIN` also reveals that the rows are being fetched with a different strategy now:

```
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys                             | key                   | key_len | ref   | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | s0    | const | PRIMARY,UNIQ_4B365660ECC836F9             | UNIQ_4B365660ECC836F9 | 767     | const |      1 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | p0    | range | idx_stock_id_datetime,IDX_B7A5F324DCD6110 | idx_stock_id_datetime | 12      | NULL  | 391090 | Using where; Using index                     | 
+----+-------------+-------+-------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
```

The access type has changed from `ref` to `range` and the extra column says it's able to get the rows straight from index whereas before this was not the case.

Schema definitions

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `point` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `datetime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `volume` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stock_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `open` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `high` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `low` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  `close` decimal(10,3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_stock_id_datetime` (`stock_id`,`datetime`),
  KEY `IDX_B7A5F324DCD6110` (`stock_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stock` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `symbol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UNIQ_4B365660ECC836F9` (`symbol`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `point`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_B7A5F324DCD6110` FOREIGN KEY (`stock_id`) REFERENCES `stock` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Why is there a 20x speed difference between using and not using aggregate functions and how should I optimize the query to make it perform better?

Comment: The 2nd query selects fields from s0, which isn't in the FROM clause. The question makes no sense with an unparseable query.

Comment: There is no point in trying to improve performance when both queries are borken, e.g. they return unpredictable results in many columns.

Comment: You group by `YEARWEEK()` but in one yearweek, there are many different points and these points are (or could be) related to different stocks. Which of these (many) should be shown in column `symbol` for example?

Comment: The difference in plan and performance is probably due to the missing `(s0.symbol = 'AMD')` in the 2nd query, not the fewer aggregate functions.

Comment: @ypercube Slight brain fart there. I fixed the second query so that the only difference between the two is using and not using aggregate functions. The missing `(s0.symbol = 'AMD')` was a typo and the difference in performance is still there.

Comment: It's not because of aggregate functions. p0.high/low/open/close/volume need to be read from the base table in the 1st query but not the 2nd, as they are not in the select list. The selected columns id and datetime are satisfied by the index in the 2nd query. Add p0.high/low/open/close/volume to the select list in the 2nd query and you will see the same behaviour.

Comment: @Phil Ah, this indeed is the case. Are there any ways to make the initial query perform any better?

Comment: @ypercube I'm selecting a specific stock from the stock table, join its points and group them by yearweek. I'm sorry if I'm missing something obvious here, but which part of the query do you think is broken? Yes, ´p0.id´ and ´p0.datetime´ make no sense in the context of the query, they are there to keep the application from blowing up.

Comment: Oh ok, if you remove the `point.id` and `datetime` it does make sense. I was thinking of the 2nd query (first version) without the `(s0.symbol = 'AMD')`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is one difference in the two execution plans that I think is relevant. Both queries use the `idx_stock_id_datetime (stock_id, datetime)` index but if you notice the `key_len`, the first query has `4` while the second has `12`.

This means that the first query uses only the `stock_id` (first part) of the index, while the second uses both parts.

The reason that the second query can do that, is that it doesn't any need to do any aggregated calculation on the table. All the requested information is available from the index. (Wait, all, what about `p0.id`? This is also included in the index, as it's the clustered key of the table so it is included in all other non-clustered inices).

The first query though has a harder job to do. For every group it has to do several aggregations which require `open`, `low`, `high` columns which are not included in the index, so it has to scan a large part of the table - if not all of it - to find those values.

To clarify, what slows the first query is not the aggregations but the columns needed for these aggregations that cannot be found on the index.

---

Since MySQL has no materialized views or computed columns yet, and if speeding this query is crucial, you could recreate the `point` table, altering the indices to:

```
PRIMARY KEY `idx_stock_id_datetime` (`stock_id`,`datetime`),
  UNIQUE KEY  (`id`),
```

effectively making the `(stock_id, datetime)` the clustered index of the table. This will mean that all the values you need for a specific stock and a range of dates are consecutively stored in the clustered index - which in fact is the table. As this nice explanation of InnoDB clustered index says, you could call InnoDB tables **index-organized tables**: [Understanding InnoDB clustered indexes](http://www.ovaistariq.net/521/understanding-innodb-clustered-indexes/)

This will affect however all other non-SELECT operations on the table. The clustered index will no longer be ever-increasing, so depending on how you use the table, e.g. how often you are inserting/deleting/updating, you may see slowing down of the performance, when InnoDB is rearranging the values or inserting in the middle of the table/index.

---

Another solution might be to create another table that is a substitute of a materialized view and holds the results you need:

```
stock_id,
YEARWEEK(datetime) AS label,
KG_FIRST(open, datetime) AS open,
MAX(high) AS high,
MIN(low) AS low,
KG_LAST(close, datetime) AS close,
SUM(volume) AS volume
```

and is updated with triggers when rows are inserted/updated/deleted in the `point` table.

Comment: Did you not see my comment?

Comment: @Phil: Yes, and I agree with your comment.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks! I went with the first approach and it's performing much better. For some reason I thought for each row regular indexes would store a pointer to its relating row. Am I right to assume that in the 1st query MySQL didn't use the whole index as a scan in the table must have been made anyway?

Comment: *"I thought for each row regular indexes would store a pointer to its relating row."* Yes, they do. But it's expensive to retrieve 75000 rows data, scattered in the table. It's much more cheap if all the data are in the same place.